# SPARQL query all persons who lived through the 20th century in DBPedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to query all persons who lived through the entire 20th century in DBPedia.
Im using https://dbpedia.org/sparql/ to process my query. I have limited the output to 20.

The query I've tried is the following:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?personName ?birthDate ?deathDate
WHERE {
    FILTER (?birthDate < "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date AND ?deathDate > "1999-12-31"^^xsd:date).
    ?p rdf:type dbo:Person.
    ?p dbp:name ?personName.
    ?p dbp:birthDate ?birthDate.
    ?p dbp:deathDate ?deathDate.
}
LIMIT 20.
```

In the output all person died after 1999-12-31 but they weren't born before 1900-01-01.
Why is my query wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for you time.

Comment: the problem are the datatypes. Check one of the persons by looking at e.g. https://dbpedia.org/page/Errol_Scorcher - `dbp:birthDate` is just an integer value here, it#s impossible to compare an int with a date. You should use the `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` namespace instead to have strongly types properties and values. In your case, use `dbo:birthDate` and `dbo:deathDate`

Comment: And yes, once you have done this, you'll see the poor data quality of Wikipedia/DBpedia for many entries ... so quite often either birth date or death date are wrong - you could do a sanity check like `bind( year(?deathDate) - year(?birthDate) - if(month(?deathDate)<month(?birth) || (month(?deathDate)=month(?birthDate) && day(?deathDate)<day(?birthDate)),1,0) as ?age ) FILTER(?age < 110)` but this would lead to less results and we do not know which of the dates is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to integer values being included in the query results, and can be resolved using the DATATYPE() function in the same or a new FILTER() section.

For example:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?personName ?birthDate ?deathDate
WHERE 
    {
        ?person rdf:type dbo:Person;
        dbp:name ?personName;
        dbp:birthDate ?birthDate;
        dbp:deathDate ?deathDate.
    
        #This FILTER ensures that only xsd:date values are returned
        FILTER(DATATYPE(?birthDate) = xsd:date && DATATYPE(?deathDate) = xsd:date).
    
        FILTER (?birthDate < "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date && ?deathDate > "1999-12-31"^^xsd:date).
    
    }
LIMIT 20
```

[Live Query Definition](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0ASELECT%20%3FpersonName%20%3FbirthDate%20%3FdeathDate%0AWHERE%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbp%3Aname%20%3FpersonName%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbp%3AbirthDate%20%3FbirthDate%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbp%3AdeathDate%20%3FdeathDate.%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23This%20FILTER%20ensures%20that%20only%20xsd%3Adate%20values%20are%20returned%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER(DATATYPE(%3FbirthDate)%20%3D%20xsd%3Adate%20%26%26%20DATATYPE(%3FdeathDate)%20%3D%20xsd%3Adate).%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20(%3FbirthDate%20%3C%20%221900-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%20%26%26%20%3FdeathDate%20%3E%20%221999-12-31%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate).%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0ALIMIT%2020&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)

[Live Query Result](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbp%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%3FpersonName+%3FbirthDate+%3FdeathDate%0D%0AWHERE+%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++%3Fperson+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3APerson%3B%0D%0A++++++++dbp%3Aname+%3FpersonName%3B%0D%0A++++++++dbp%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate%3B%0D%0A++++++++dbp%3AdeathDate+%3FdeathDate.%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++++++%23This+FILTER+ensures+that+only+xsd%3Adate+values+are+returned%0D%0A++++++++FILTER%28DATATYPE%28%3FbirthDate%29+%3D+xsd%3Adate+%26%26+DATATYPE%28%3FdeathDate%29+%3D+xsd%3Adate%29.%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++++++FILTER+%28%3FbirthDate+%3C+%221900-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate+%26%26+%3FdeathDate+%3E+%221999-12-31%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%29.%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+20&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)

[DATATYPE() Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-datatype)